# Transform JSON from sql query in php (for upload Facebook Offline Conversion / Graph API)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, select

by a SQL database query I want to create a JSON to upload the existing data via the Facebook Graph API into Facebook Offline Conversion.

For this I need a JSON, which consists of arrays and objects. Here is an example.

```
[{"match_keys":{"lead_id":"1234"},"event_time":1477632399,
   "event_name":"Purchase","currency":"USD","value":2}]
```

How can I extend my query so that I also have objects in my arrays?

Here is the current code:

```
    //Create database connection
$dblink = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);

//Check connection was successful
if ($dblink->connect_errno) {
    printf("Failed to connect to database");
    exit();
}

//Fetch 3 rows from actor table
$result = $dblink->query("SELECT
        id as 'lead_id',
        DATE_FORMAT(imported, '%m-%d-%Y %H:%i:%s') as event_time,
       (CASE when email > 0 THEN 'CompleteRegistration' ELSE 'CompleteRegistration' END) as event_name


        FROM marketing.cmx_data where id > 235164");

//Initialize array variable
$dbdata = array();

//Fetch into associative array
while ( $row = $result->fetch_assoc())  {
    $dbdata[]=$row;
}


//// Facebook Uploader


//Print array in JSON format


$data = $dbdata;



// Replace with your access token
$access_token = 'XXXX';

// Turn Data to JSON
$data_json = json_encode(array($data));

// Fill available fields
$fields = array();
$fields['access_token'] = $access_token;
$fields['upload_tag'] = "orders";
$fields['data'] = $data_json;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    // Replace with your offline_event_set_id
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/XXXXXXXX/events",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($fields),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        //"content-type: multipart/form-data",
        "Accept: application/json"),
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo "\nResult encode";
echo($result);

die();
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close($ch);
```

The output of my code is a "simple" JSON, without objects.

```
[{"lead_id":"235230","event_time":"06-07-2020 
  12:10:24","event_name":"CompleteRegistration"},...]
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL 5.7 or higher, you can use `JSON_OBJECT()`  to generate json objects and `JSON_ARRAYAGG()` to aggregate multiple rows in an array.

It looks like you want:

```
SELECT
    JSON_ARRAYAGG(
        JSONOBJECT(
            'match_keys', JSONOBJECT('lead_id', lead_id),
            'event_time', UNIX_TIMESTAMP(imported),
            'event_name', event_name,
            'currency',   currency,
            'value',      value 
        )
    ) res
FROM marketing.cmx_data 
WHERE id > 235164
```

This gives you a resultset with just one row and one column, that contains the expected JSON content.

Comment: Thanks for your sql. I've tested this successfully, but the output around terminal looks a bit strange? 
Do you have an idea how [ \ ] can get there? The Output: '[[{"JSON_ARRAYAGG(\n        JSON_OBJECT(\n            'match_keys', JSON_OBJECT('lead_id', ID),\n            'event_time', (imported),\n            'event_name', (CASE when email > 0 THEN 'CompleteRegistration' ELSE 'CompleteRegistration' END)\n        )\n    )":"[{\"event_name\": \"CompleteRegistration\", \"event_time\": \"2020-06-07 20:22:29.000000\", \"match_keys\": {\"lead_id\": 235336}}]"}]]